# AWS boto3 retrieve more than 1000 folders name, but not object names under the folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket with the following structure:

```
bucket_name/level1/level2/level3/level4/..../somefilename1.txt, somefilename2.txt,... somefilename(n).txt
```

where multiple files can be under the root 'folder'.

I need to get list of 'folders' names at level1 and level2 only. I don't need to drill past level2.  Stated differently, I just need to get back a list of: `bucket_name/level1/level2/` names.   The list can be over a little 2000 items.

If I use:

```
s3_keys = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/')
```

I successfully get the list I am looking for, but limited to 1000 records.

I googled and paginator seems to be an option:

```
        keys = []
        paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
        operation_parameters = {'Bucket': bucket,
                                'Prefix': filepath}
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)
        for page in page_iterator:
            keys.append(page['Contents'])
```

But this paginator approach is returning every object path under the bucket .... this can be hundred of thousands of objects paths.

I just need the top 2 level path

Please advise how to accomplish this task. Thank you.

Example directory structure:

```
my_bucket/machine1_id/part1_id/../../../..
my_bucket/machine1_id/part2_id/../../../..
.
.
my_bucket/machineN_id/part1_id/../../../..
my_bucket/machineN_id/part2_id/../../../..
.
.
my_bucket/machineN_id/part(n)_id/../../../..
.
.
my_bucket/Building1_id/Room1_size/.../../../..
my_bucket/Building1_id/Room2_size/.../../../..
.
.
my_bucket/BuildingN_id/Room1_size/.../../../..
my_bucket/BuildingN_id/Room2_size/.../../../..
.
.
my_bucket/BuildingN_id/RoomN_size/.../../../..
.
.
```

and so on.   I am only interested in getting a list of all my_bucket/1st_level/2n_level/   and nothing past that.  In my case can be more that 2000 items

The returned String list that I am seeking would be something like this

```
[
    "my_bucket/machine1_id/part1_id/",
    "my_bucket/machine1_id/part2_id/",
    .
    .
    "my_bucket/machineN_id/part1_id/",
    "my_bucket/machineN_id/part2_id/",
    .
    .
    "my_bucket/machineN_id/part(n)_id/",
    .
    .
    "my_bucket/Building1_id/Room1_size/",
    "my_bucket/Building1_id/Room2_size/",
    .
    .
    "my_bucket/BuildingN_id/Room1_size/",
    "my_bucket/BuildingN_id/Room2_size/",
    .
    .
    "my_bucket/BuildingN_id/RoomN_size/",
    .
    .
]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify... are you wanting to retrieve **object names** or the names of the **folders**? Are you wanting to go "into" sub-folders? Feel free to edit your question and provide a sample hierarchy and a list of what you are wanting as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with a native boto3 option.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    if obj.key.endswith('/'):
        print(obj.key)
```

This will print all the folders (that is actually every key ends with / ).

Comment: Thanks .... This is what I am actually doing now .... resulting in couple of hundred thousands keys coming back.   Thanks for the confirmation.   I will go ahead and mark as answered to close.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a listing of all objects inside `level1/level2`, you could use:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket='bucket-name',
    Delimiter='/',
    Prefix='level1/level2/',
)
for page in response_iterator:
    for object in page['Contents']:
        print(object['Key'])
```

Comment: Apology for not being clear.   'level1/level2/' is not fixed names.   This is why I need the list of all permutations of these 2 levels.   level1 can be 100s of different path 'names', and level2 can have 10s of path 'names' for each level1 path name.   Hope this clears it a bit.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a sample directory structure and a sample of the output you wish to achieve.

Comment: I edited.   I hope this clarifies a bit more.   Thank you for your help

Comment: Please include a list of what output you want for the directory structure you have provided. For example, it is unclear whether you want object names or folder names.

Comment: added an output example ... I am just looking for the folders names ... basically a list of strings as I show in the edited question